# Predictive Intelligence Code not pushing info to data extensions, why?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, einstein-recommendations

I have the following data extensions available;

```
CloudPages_DataExtension
IGO_PRODUCTATTRIBS
IGO_PRODUCTS
IGO_PROFILES
IGO_PURCHASES
IGO_VIEWS
PI_ABANDONED_CART_EVENT
PI_ABANDONED_CART_ITEMS
PI_CONTENT
PI_CONTENTATTRIBS
PI_CONTENTVIEWS
PI_SESSIONS
PI_TRIGGEREVENT
PI_TRIGGEREVENTDETAIL
PREDICTIVE_SCORES
SocialPages_DataExtension
```

I want to receive info on abandoned cart items in MC from the external web page. Right now I see in the implementation status that items are received and the timestamp is corresponding to the activity I execute but no data appears in the Data extensions, why?

This text is taken from Predictive web > Integration Instructions

> Marketing Cloud begins collecting data immediately after you implement the Collect Code on your website. However, depending on your website traffic, it may take up to one month to detect enough activity to power the algorithms. Once we receive catalog items, we will notify you immediately, by email, that you can begin creating predictive content.

What does this mean? What are the thresholds for "enough data"? How do I get live data from the external web page into visible data records in the MC data extensions?

Comment: Does anyone have any information about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: As per the January '18 release, einstein data extension can now be enabled through the UI.

these data extensions are created in the BU's as a standard, however, in order to actually get data in them, you would need to engage the professional services team. They can get you up and running - it requires the enabling of what is known as a **Raw Data Feed Integration**, and this has a cost associated with it.

Until that has been done, data is stored in AWS, and can only be accessed, manually, via the web and mobile analytics dashboard.

Comment: Do you have any link to this information? I have looked all over marketing cloud help pages and searched on developer pages for "Raw Data Feed Integration" but I cant find any info?

Comment: There is none - you need to engage professional services or account Executive for this :)

Comment: I can add that typically, to my knowledge, it requires a scoping exercise, given that many environments feature some of the same data, but also some different data sets or different affinities etc. - which all needs to be integrated correctly.

Comment: Hi @KennethWagner. How much does it cost? Do you know?

Comment: @SelimSevim - it is free as of the january release, at least for the data feeds, as it's done via the UI