# Accessing those IGO_ and PI_ data extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

I need to access the data collected via collect code and stored in the data extensions (DE) starting with PI_ or IGO_

I can see the DEs but they are all empty. I believe a SFMC service team can make the data come through, but somewhere I have read that it is possible to access the data via queries.

I made the simplest test, duplicating one of the DE:s ("IGO_PROFILES") and trying to populate it with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM IGO_PROFILES
```

The result is that my target DE is as empty as it's "parent".

Any ideas on how to query those DEs or access the data without asking support for help?

The data I want is information on location, paths, referring sites. We don't have specific products so fields like "sku" is not interesting.

The data is visible in the Web and Mobile tab, so that part works.

Please fill me in on this. I think information/documentation is really poor regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding I think you need to contact your SFMC representative to have it activated before you can access it at all. That was the information I recieved in another thread [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167139/predictive-intelligence-code-not-pushing-info-to-data-extensions-why).

Answer (score 1):

After the code is added to the website, you need to enable Einstein Recommendation DE: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_enable_pb_data_extensions.htm&type=5

Data will be stored in non-sendable DEs: PI_ or IGO_