# Pushing web activity data to Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We need to push marketing activity data to Salesforce contact/lead object.
What is the best way to push key activity data (showing high interest) into Sales cloud?

Eloque does it via closed tasks which show up in the activities area, which is one way of doing it.

Please provide a solution example how you have solved this with marketing cloud.

Comment: This sounds more like a Sales Cloud question, rather than Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Web & Mobile Analytics to collect information about your visitors’ online behaviour. This can be stored in [specific date extensions.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167139/predictive-intelligence-code-not-pushing-info-to-data-extensions-why)

You can query these, to derive the information needed, create a custom object in Sales Cloud, and populate it with data from this query.

You can get an overview of Web & Mobile Analytics in [this help article.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_anb_web__mobile_analytics.htm&type=5)

Comment: This we partly knew about but it has costs involved and custom sales cloud development is needed. If this is enabled, is there an easy way to make it available for sales?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. This sounds tome like a lead nurturing use case. Most of clients I work with on these projects are using Pardot to achieve this.

Comment: Journey builder is our tool at the moment. Is pardot then a replacement for journey builder or an add-on? Have you seen implementations that push activity data to salesforce without Pardot?

Comment: Only custom built solutions, as mentioned in my answer above. Pardot has Engagement Studio, which offers similar functionality to Journey Builder. Overall, Pardot is more of a B2B solution, where Marketing Cloud is a B2C platform.

Comment: Ok. I’m curious to hear how different custom solutions have been done. I’ll add this to original question.

Comment: In this case, Eloqua is indeed more similar to Pardot - which also offers closed loop reporting on e.g. won opportunities